# Flutter SingelChildScrollView for column is not working

Tags: flutter

I have the following code in flutter. The first Expanded with flex 1 can be scrolled if needed but the next Expanded with flex 2 and the list of widgets (`createButtons(answerList)`) can not be scrolled and I can not figure out why? Both have the scrollable in them!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../backend/QuestionaireConstants/question.dart';
import '../../backend/utils/constants.dart';
import '../../backend/utils/setupcomingRoute.dart';
import '../../backend/widgets/button_content.dart';
import '../../backend/widgets/reusable_cart.dart';

int selectedAnswer = -1;
int counter = 0;

Color determineColor(int selection) {
  return selectedAnswer == selection ? Colors.white : Colors.black;
}

class SelectionWindow extends StatefulWidget {
  const SelectionWindow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SelectionWindowState createState() => _SelectionWindowState();
}

class _SelectionWindowState extends State<SelectionWindow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as List<Question>;
    int count = args[0].counter;
    int arraylen = args.length;
    List answerList = args[count].possibleAnswers;

    String upcomingRoute = setUpcomingRoute(count, arraylen, args);

    List<Widget> createButtons(list) {
      List<Widget> buttons = [];

      //creating single choice buttons
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        buttons.add(
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedAnswer = i;
                    });
                  },
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    colour: selectedAnswer == i
                        ? Colors.blue.shade900
                        : Colors.blue.shade200,
                    cardChild: ButtonContent(
                      label: args[count].possibleAnswers[i],
                      textColour: determineColor(i),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }

      return buttons;
    }

    //showing error screen
    Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {
      return showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Alert'),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListBody(
                children: const <Widget>[
                  Text('Please select one answer before continuing.'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(
                  'Approve',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: backwardsArrowBlack,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: appBarText,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Text(args[count].questionText,
                    style: multipleChoiceTextStyle),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  child: Column(
                    children: createButtons(answerList),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              if (args[0].counter > 0) {
                                args[0].counter -= 1;
                                args[count - 1].givenAnswers.clear();
                              }
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            child: backwardsButton,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              if (selectedAnswer == -1) {
                                _showMyDialog();
                              } else {
                                args[count].givenAnswers.add(args[count]
                                    .possibleAnswers[selectedAnswer]);
                                selectedAnswer = -1;
                                if (args[0].counter == arraylen - 1) {
                                  args[0].counter += 1;
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/endScreen',
                                          arguments: args)
                                      .then((_) => setState(() {}));
                                } else {
                                  args[0].counter += 1;
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                                    context,
                                    upcomingRoute,
                                    arguments: args,
                                  ).then((_) => setState(() {}));
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            child: forwardButton,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The emulator shows the following error in case of having many answers in the list that are not fit in the page:

```
    ====================================================================================================
D/EGL_emulation(15191): app_time_stats: avg=10.35ms min=0.79ms max=89.84ms count=52
D/EGL_emulation(15191): app_time_stats: avg=104.68ms min=0.77ms max=1043.27ms count=11
D/EGL_emulation(15191): app_time_stats: avg=69.44ms min=11.30ms max=1017.83ms count=19
I/flutter (15191): type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<int>'
D/EGL_emulation(15191): app_time_stats: avg=151.10ms min=0.54ms max=925.70ms count=12

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 203 pixels on the bottom.
```

Comment: are you trying to  make scrollable for full body?

Comment: Can you try to lift your SingleChildScrollView up? As the first child in your Expanded

Comment: @YeasinSheikh not all body. The first and second Expanded. The first one works.

Comment: @targiasld not sure what you mean, but it is the first child in its Expanded children under column.

Comment: Can you simplify the widget that will reproduce the same error

Comment: There is no error. The problem is that in case of many answers in the list the scroll functionality is not there. So user can not click on forward symbol in that case.

Comment: ok, sorry. the error is 
A RenderFlex overflowed by 203 pixels on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../backend/QuestionaireConstants/question.dart';
import '../../backend/utils/constants.dart';
import '../../backend/utils/setupcomingRoute.dart';
import '../../backend/widgets/button_content.dart';
import '../../backend/widgets/reusable_cart.dart';

int selectedAnswer = -1;
int counter = 0;

Color determineColor(int selection) {
  return selectedAnswer == selection ? Colors.white : Colors.black;
}

class SelectionWindow extends StatefulWidget {
  const SelectionWindow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SelectionWindowState createState() => _SelectionWindowState();
}

class _SelectionWindowState extends State<SelectionWindow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as List<Question>;
    int count = args[0].counter;
    int arraylen = args.length;
    List answerList = args[count].possibleAnswers;

    String upcomingRoute = setUpcomingRoute(count, arraylen, args);

    List<Widget> createButtons(list) {
      List<Widget> buttons = [];

      //creating single choice buttons
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        buttons.add(
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedAnswer = i;
                    });
                  },
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    colour: selectedAnswer == i
                        ? Colors.blue.shade900
                        : Colors.blue.shade200,
                    cardChild: ButtonContent(
                      label: args[count].possibleAnswers[i],
                      textColour: determineColor(i),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }

      return buttons;
    }

    //showing error screen
    Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {
      return showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Alert'),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListBody(
                children: const <Widget>[
                  Text('Please select one answer before continuing.'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(
                  'Approve',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: backwardsArrowBlack,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: appBarText,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Text(args[count].questionText,
                    style: multipleChoiceTextStyle),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child:  Column(
                children: createButtons(answerList),
              ),
            ),
          ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              if (args[0].counter > 0) {
                                args[0].counter -= 1;
                                args[count - 1].givenAnswers.clear();
                              }
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            child: backwardsButton,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              if (selectedAnswer == -1) {
                                _showMyDialog();
                              } else {
                                args[count].givenAnswers.add(args[count]
                                    .possibleAnswers[selectedAnswer]);
                                selectedAnswer = -1;
                                if (args[0].counter == arraylen - 1) {
                                  args[0].counter += 1;
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/endScreen',
                                          arguments: args)
                                      .then((_) => setState(() {}));
                                } else {
                                  args[0].counter += 1;
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                                    context,
                                    upcomingRoute,
                                    arguments: args,
                                  ).then((_) => setState(() {}));
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            child: forwardButton,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
  }
}
```